# How can I check for "exec" authorization using `kubectl auth can-i`?

Tags: linux, bash, kubernetes, cloud

How can I check for `exec` authorization using `kubectl auth can-i ...`?

While `get`, `create`, `delete`, etc. are considered verbs, `exec` is not, as shown below:

```
$ kubectl --kubeconfig=config-prod.yml auth can-i exec po
Warning: verb 'exec' is not a known verb
yes
```

Is `exec` authorization included in another authorization, like `create`?

Comment: `kubectl auth can-i exec po` works fine for me.

Comment: @Philippe - You don't get that warning? If the warning shows, than anything will result in "yes"

Comment: No warning for me. My `kubectl version` gives Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"19", GitVersion:"v1.19.7", GitCommit:"1dd5338295409ed
cfff11505e7bb246f0d325d15", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2021-01-13T13:23:52Z", GoVersion:"go1.1
5.5", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"windows/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"17", GitVersion:"v1.17.16", GitCommit:"d88fadbd65c5e8
bde22630d251766a634c7613b0", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2020-12-18T15:59:27Z", GoVersion:"go1.
13.15", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}

Comment: Maybe since my version is newer, you should try to `kubectl auth can-i dummy po` to see if it also says "yes" (default) for `dummy`.

Comment: It say yes too for dummy

Comment: When you want check auth for `exec` you should use `subresource` . I will explain further in a while

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Usually when someone is creating [RBAC](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/) rules and wants to check which `verbs` are available for resource using:

```
$ kubectl api-resources -o wide | grep pods
pods                              po           v1                                     true         Pod                              [create delete deletecollection get list patch update watch]
```

However it's not all. If you will use bit different approach like below:

```
$ kubectl proxy &
Starting to serve on 127.0.0.1:8001
curl http://localhost:8001/api/v1
{
  "kind": "APIResourceList",
  "groupVersion": "v1",
  "resources": [
    {
...
### You will be able to find `pods` and verbs which can be used with pods
{
      "name": "pods",
      "singularName": "",
      "namespaced": true,
      "kind": "Pod",
      "verbs": [
        "create",
        "delete",
        "deletecollection",
        "get",
        "list",
        "patch",
        "update",
        "watch"
      ],
      "shortNames": [
        "po"

### But also `pod/exec` and `pod/logs`
{
      "name": "pods/exec",
      "singularName": "",
      "namespaced": true,
      "kind": "PodExecOptions",
      "verbs": [
        "create",
        "get"
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "pods/log",
      "singularName": "",
      "namespaced": true,
      "kind": "Pod",
      "verbs": [
        "get"
      ]
```

In [Using RBAC Authorization - Referring to resources](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/#referring-to-resources) you can find information about `subresource`.

> In the Kubernetes API, most resources are represented and accessed using a string representation of their object name, such as pods for a Pod. RBAC refers to resources using exactly the same name that appears in the URL for the relevant API endpoint. Some Kubernetes APIs involve a subresource, such as the logs for a Pod

In this Documentation, you have an example with `pods/logs` but a similar situation is for `pods/exec`.

If you will use command:

```
$ kubectl auth can-i create pods/exec
yes
$ kubectl auth can-i get pods/exec
yes

## Or

$ kubectl auth can-i get pods --subresource=exec
yes
$ kubectl auth can-i create pods --subresource=exec
yes
```

Above outputs don't include `Warning` as I used `verbs` (`get` and `create`) from `pods/exec`. So that's the correct syntax, use `verb` and then `subresource`.

Why are both outputs `yes`? I used an admin role.

If you want to make some tests you can create `ServiceAccount` (test), `Role` and `RoleBinding`. `Role` yamls below:

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: Role
metadata:
  namespace: default
  name: pod-view-role
rules:
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: ["pods"]
  verbs: ["get", "list", "watch"]
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: Role
metadata:
  namespace: default
  name: pod-exec-view-role
rules:
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: ["pods/exec"]
  verbs: ["get"]
```

Outputs of `auth can-i`:

```
$ kubectl auth can-i create pods/exec --as=system:serviceaccount:default:test
no
$ kubectl auth can-i get pods/exec --as=system:serviceaccount:default:test
yes
```

About the difference between `create pods/exec` and `get pods/exec` you can check github thread [Users can exec into pods with the websocket endpoint even without `pods/exec create` privileges](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/78741). Especially in @liggitt [comment](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/78741#issuecomment-500412951):

> So the verb used with the pods/exec subresource is just supposed to indicate what HTTP method is used with that API endpoint?

That is how all the resource verbs work (with get mapping to specific verbs in the special cases list and watch). See https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authorization/#determine-the-request-verb

> So an admin building an RBAC role is expected to look at the code and figure out which HTTP methods are supported for the websocket exec endpoint?

No, the subresources and associated verbs should be included in the API doc. That would be worth an issue against https://github.com/kubernetes/website/issues/ to fix the generator to pick up those subresources

Hope it answered your question. If you still have questions, let me know.

Comment: Thank you. So, is `exec` a subresource of `pods`? That’s a little subtle. While I think of `pods` as objects (or resources), I wouldn’t think of `exec` as a resource, because “execute” is an English verb.

Comment: It can be tricky. If you will check more subsources of pods you will find `pods/attach`, `pods/binding`, `pods/eviction`,  `pods/proxy` and few more. Similar with other resources like objects `services/proxy`, `services/status`.

Comment: “with get mapping to specific verbs like list and watch”, you mean HTTP GET?

Comment: Last lines about differences were took from [this github thread](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/78741) you might find there more accurate explanation.